# what is the instruction count when it is executed?

Tags: c++, assembly

I need help with this. Can someone please explain to me step by step how to do this. I really want to learn this.

this is the code

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i > 10) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: What is the question? (What exactly do you mean by "instruction"?) Note that the compiler will probably optimise all this out to nothing, because it doesn't do anything, so the answer might be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Till `i <= 10` there will be no increment in `x`.
After *i = 11* the `x` increases 10 times for each increase in `i` as `j` loops for ten times.
For eg: if *i=11*, *x=0* at this point.. but in the loop of `j` it increase by ten i.e `x = x + 10`
So final value of **x = 10*89 = 890**.  `89` because of *i=11* to *i=99*